# Is it possible to define an F# operator that applies multiple functions to a single argument (almost the opposite of the ||> operator)?

Tags: f#

My attempt to do this is here (forgive the for loop - I was just curious to see if this was possible):

```
let (|>>) a (b : ('a -> unit) list) = 
    for x in b do
        x a
```

but when I try to use it I get the error 
[image]

Comment: I should have included that x in the image is a list of two functions that take a parameter of the same type as 'arm'

`let x = [clearArmProductMappings; clearLocationArmMappings]`

Comment: Are you defining `|>>` _before_ trying to use it? That `None of the types` error message can occur if the function you're trying to use is defined further down the file or isn't imported correctly. Otherwise, your function definition seems ok.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I had defined it in a module I thought I had set for 'AutoOpen' but it wasn't.
Problem solved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `None of the types error` message can occur if the function you're trying to use is defined further down the file or isn't imported correctly. Otherwise, your function definition seems ok.

Answer (score 5):

I would discourage the use of a custom operator for this. I think they should be used very rarely. This one doesn't seem general enough to be worth defining and could make code hard to read. Here is one alternative:

```
[ printf "%A"; printfn "%A" ] |> List.iter ((|>) 1)
```

But it's even clearer and shorter to write out your operator definition inline:

```
for f in [ printf "%A"; printfn "%A" ] do f 1
```